# How to create a queue to store incoming files added to a folder, when more than one file is dropped in at a time?

Tags: c#, list, file, memory, filesystemwatcher

I made a service which monitors a folder to see when a new file is added. When a new file is added, the file is broken down by line (each line is stored in a list), and the data stored in each line is then encoded into a QR code image. The QR image is then saved to a new folder. This whole process works BUT when I drop more than one file into a folder at the same time, my service only encoded the lines of one of the files.

Issue: How can I create a queue to store newly added files (when more than one file is dropped in at a time) in a list which I can pull from once it encodes the current file in the queue??

First I am using System.Collections.Concurrent queue to make a method to grabdata in the queue.

**Watcher Methods:**
*Start the service/file system monitor*

```
public void Start()
{
    newfolders = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["parsefiles"];
    pathtomonitor = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pathtomonitor"];

    pathforpaths = newfolders;

    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathforpaths);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    pathforprocess = newfolders + @"\processdata";

    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathtomonitor);
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathforprocess);

    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(pathtomonitor);

    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.FileName;

    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;

    //add event handlers
    watcher.Created += watcher_Created;
}
```

*Get File added to folder and create QR code*

```
private static void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
    {

        if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(_lastTimeFileWatcherEventRaised)
            .TotalMilliseconds < 1000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Short time between previous event and change event");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("file: {0} changed at time:{1}", e.Name,
            DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (GetAccessLoop(pathtomonitor + "\\" + e.Name))
        {
            parsefile(pathtomonitor + "\\" + e.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("worked");
        }
        else
        {
            //writetologs("Was not able to get access to" + e.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("didnt work");
        }

        _lastTimeFileWatcherEventRaised = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

**ISSUE: **Only one of the files gets stored in the string not both. I want all files added to the folder to be stored so I can pull the files from the list one at a time and delete them once they are done being encoded.

How do I store all of the files detected by filesystem watcher so I can save files that have been dropped in at the same time?

Would I use a memory stream?????

Comment: What does the code look like for the file system watcher? Are you sure `GetExclusiveAccess()` is called once for each file dropped?

Comment: Hello Eric @EricJ. Thank you for getting back to me!!!!

I added the rest of my filesystem watcher code.

What I am doing now is creating a list that stores all of the files in the folder I am watching. When a file is added to the folder, it will store the name in another list. Then I will compare the two lists to see if they have the same files, if not, create a QR code for the files that are not in the added files list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sleeping in the event handler is a bad idea. Event handlers should be as quick as possible. You want the event handler to make note of the new file (for example, by adding the file's name or path to a thread-safe collection such as a ConcurrentQueue) then exit. You then want a separate task to process entries in that collection as necessary for your program.

Here's a simplified example:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var pathtomonitor = @"C:\Temp\FileWatcherExample";
    
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathtomonitor);

    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(pathtomonitor);

    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.FileName;

    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;

    //add event handlers
    watcher.Created += watcher_Created;
    
    // As programmed, this will await forever since there 
    // isn't a mechanism to end ProcessNewFiles()
    await ProcessNewFiles();
    
}

ConcurrentQueue<string> createdFiles = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

private async Task ProcessNewFiles()
{
    while (true) // In production code we'd use a cancellation token to exit
    {
        while (createdFiles.TryDequeue(out var path))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Processing {path}");
        }
        // This is more efficienty handled with Channels, but we'll
        // introduce a small delay here to keep the code example
        // simple
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}

private void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"New file: {e.FullPath}");
        createdFiles.Enqueue(e.FullPath);
    }
}
```

I am a fan of the suggestion in the other answer, to move files into an "Archived" folder once they have been processed.

Comment: Hi @Eric J. Thank you for your help!!!! I am trying to fix my service to follow your setup, but I am hav9ing issues starting my service.....

Your simplified example (which I added my data) I put into a new class called "FileWatcher". How do I call the watcher to start watching and run my service?

In my Program.cs 
I tried to call it by var exitcode = HostFactory.Run(x =>{x.Service<FileWatcher>(s => {s.ConstrucctUsing(filewatcher => new FileWatcher()); });    x.RunAsLocalSystem(); }); but it didnt work! It starts the service but quickly closes it.

Comment: You can inject the file watcher class as a singleton in dependency injection and do necessary initialization in that class' constructor.

Comment: Hi Eric! @Eric J. Thank you for getting back to me. I really appreciate your help.

As a new coder, do you have suggestions of videos or forums I can reference to understand dependency injection? Is the concept/topic you are suggesting of creating a Task fall under dependency injection? I am a visual learner and like to learn code by following along with videos. Given your comments/answers, I would appreciate gaining insight into resources you have used in the past that you found the most helpful to learn C#.

Comment: Dependency injection will create an instance of a class for you at an appropriate time. That "appropriate time" depends on the scope you specify. For this, a singleton scope is appropriate, meaning there will be exactly one instance of the class in your program. You don't need to explicitly create any tasks for this, though the async/await keywords will create tasks for you. I haven't watched this particular video, but Tim Corey does a good job explaining programming concepts. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hhpq7oYcpGE

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are polling for new files every 2000 seconds without any way to see what was there and what is new? Do you need to keep old files in the same folder where they were delivered?

Can you create an "archived" subfolder and move processed files into there? This way you know that any file in the current folder (delivery folder) needs to be processed still. Additionally you wouldn't ever move a file to archive in case any part of the process fails.

Additionally, it sounds like you aren't storing the list of files added but just one? Can we see how you get access to the file list of what is new?

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for getting back to me and helping!  I added the rest of my filesystem watcher code to my question. 
I agree on creating an "archived folder"! I am going to create a list to store all of the "encoded files" and compare it to the files in the folder being watched. If there are files missing in the "enconded files" list (in archived folder but not this folder) then take the name of the missing file and encode it.